# Why some of my commits on Git signed as my username while the others as my name?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitlab

Why are some of my commits in Git signed as my username while the others as my name? Once a time commits started to sign with name.

And the other "anomaly", may be related to this:

When I try to rebase from some of my branch and resolve the conflicts, IntelliJ Idea shows me in resolving dialog panes not my latest commit on branch but the latest one which is signed by my name, not my username like the latest commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in commit authors never leads to a conflict.
During rebase, commits are applied one by one and conflict may occur during any of them. 
The situation where you can see only a particular username is a coincidence.

You can check this behavior in the command line as well.

You can read more on rebase here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because you did not set your commit email address correctly. See [this guide](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/setting-your-commit-email-address) for details on how to do this.

Step 1/2: (local gits) In all git repositories on your computer, run:

```sh
$ git config --global user.email "email@example.com"
$ git config --global user.name "your name"
```

(added `git config --global user.name "your name"` to reflect op's comment)

Step 2/2: (Github) Then you need to go on to Github and [set the same email address as your commit email](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/setting-your-commit-email-address#setting-your-commit-email-address-on-github).

Comment: hmm. this did not help me (. The thing that I probably had done before this began, - I changed my git password, before this, I guess, everything was allright... but I am not sure, cause, imho it could not be a proper reason

Comment: git config --global user.name "Ostap Strashevskii"
- this helps me, but i still have a problem with rebasing, maybe it is separate one

Comment: Not a user of that IDE, maybe there is some setting in IntelliJ IDEA related to this? Added a tag to your question, hopefully that would increase your chance of getting help.